# How can I show that the minimum is first sucess distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n \ldots$ with probability mass function:

$$p_X(-1)=\frac{1}{4},\, p_X(0)=\frac{1}{2},\, p_X(1)=\frac{1}{4}.$$

We introduce a new random variable $N=$ min$\{n\mid X_n=0\}$.

I have to show that $N\in Fs(\frac{1}{2})$ (first time success).

Here in other words, $N$ is the least number $n$ such that $X_n=0$, right?

How shoud i treat it? The variable $N$ makes me about confused,

Comment: If the $X_i$ are independent then you are dealing here with negative binomial distribution. Have a look at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an 'intuitive' approach:
The probability that you have succes on your first (and any other) try is $\frac 12$. The probability of having success on the second try is $(1-\frac 12)\frac12=\frac 14$. On the $n$'th try, this is $(1-\frac 12)^{n-1}\frac 12=\frac1{2^n}$, because the first $n-1$ trials failed and the $n$'th one succeeded. Now, you can calculated the expected value of the number of trials:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\frac 1{2^i}
$$
Mathematica tells me this equals $2$, so the expected number of trials before you get $0$ as outcome is $2$.

**EDIT**
We have the following equalities:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i\frac 1{2^i}
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^i}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^i}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k+1}\cdot 1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}\\
&=2
\end{align}